# angularjs: how to do fire-and-forget with $http

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I need to do a post request in which I'm not interested  in the response (Fire And Forget)

I found a way on how to do this

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { xhr.abort(); }
```

[source](http://ajaxian.com/archives/ajaxian-fire-and-forget-pattern)

But in angular things are a bit different. For example, if using `$http`

```
var promise = $http.post(url, data);
```

I don't see how I can get the `xhr` object ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, you can use the [timeout param on $http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#usage_parameters) to cancel a request.
Beginning with [AngularJS v.1.1.5](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/9f4f5937112655a9881d3281da8e72035bc8b180) you can now even use a promise to abort the request:

```
var defer = $q.defer();
$http.get('/example', { timeout: defer.promise }).success(callback);
// [...]
defer.resolve();
```

Comment: thnx a lot. Why is there a callback ? I guess you can do it without the `.success(..)` part? Actually, it would be a nice feature that if no callback is defined for `success` and `error` a **Fire and forget** policy is applied  :)

Comment: You're right, you don't need the `success` callback. Won't there be a response from your server? Because otherwise, it makes more sense to just send a regular `POST` and ignore the response, as user1744968 suggested.

Comment: There no response from the server, I just need to post some data. The problem is that in the current situation I get a pending request and finally a 503 error

Comment: This is a cool approach, however it didn´t work for me when i needed multiple fire'n'forget in parallel - if i used `$q.defer` in a loop, only one request would get cancelled on `reseolve`, and if i used `Promise.all()` then only first request would fire :/

Answer (score 2):

So you want to make a post without caring about the answer? In that case you can just make and http request using `$http.post(url, data)` and then send some dummy response from the server (like `true`).